# How to add a custom function in a Drupal theme?

Tags: theming

At WordPress there is a well-known way to add a custom function for the theme and hook the code to the  like this:

```
function add_customcode_header(){
    if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en')
      {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cookie-consent/cookieconsent.min.css" />
<script src="/cookie-consent/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
window.cookieconsent.initialise({
  "palette": {
    "popup": {
      "background": "#000000"
    },
    "button": {
      "background": "#ffffff"
    }
  },
  "showLink": false,
  "position": "bottom-left",
  "content": {
    "message": "This website uses cookies to give you the best, most relevant experience. Using this website means you are Ok with this. However, if you would like to, you can change your cookie settings at any time.",
    "dismiss": "Got it!",
    "link": "Learn more"
  }
})});
</script>';
    } 
      else
      {
        echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cookie-consent/cookieconsent.min.css" />
<script src="/cookie-consent/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
window.cookieconsent.initialise({
  "palette": {
    "popup": {
      "background": "#000000"
    },
    "button": {
      "background": "#ffffff"
    }
  },
  "showLink": false,
  "position": "bottom-left",
  "content": {
    "message": "This website uses cookies to give you the best, most relevant experience. Using this website means you are Ok with this. However, if you would like to, you can change your cookie settings at any time.",
    "dismiss": "Got it!",
    "link": "Learn more"
  }
})});
</script>';
      }
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_customcode_header');
```

How to adjust this code to work on Drupal 7 theme? I need to place the code on all front-end pages header according to the language. Where do I put it?

**Edit:** Sorry, I that did not provided enough information. I need to add this code to the `<head></head>` section of every page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cookie-consent/cookieconsent.min.css" />
<script src="/cookie-consent/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
window.cookieconsent.initialise({
  "palette": {
    "popup": {
      "background": "#000000"
    },
    "button": {
      "background": "#ffffff"
    }
  },
  "showLink": false,
  "position": "bottom-left",
  "content": {
    "message": "This website uses cookies to give you the best, most relevant experience. Using this website means you are Ok with this. However, if you would like to, you can change your cookie settings at any time.",
    "dismiss": "Got it!",
    "link": "Learn more"
  }
})});
</script>
```

There are 3 languages on the website and I need to place a separate code for each of the language.

Comment: Not sure what the downvotes are for, but you should look over the D7 docs on theming and theme hooks, everything you'd want to know and transposing knowledge can be found there.

Comment: @Kevin It could be the down-votes are for the OP not explaining correctly what the code does. I totally agree that reading the documentation about theming would be a good start, or the OP would have many problems with converting code to Drupal.

Comment: @Kevin @kiamlaluno sorry guys, I just updated the thread to be more clear. I`ve worked with WordPress previously but Drupal is a bit different CMS.

Comment: Well... you certainly don't want to approach it like this.

Comment: @Kevin What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: This is css and Js so you’ll want to look in the theming docs about how to add custom style and scripts to a theme. It’s oretty straightforward no PHP needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since `add_action('wp_head', 'add_customcode_header')` would add the output of `add_customcode_header()` to the `<head>` tag, the Drupal 7 equivalent is implementing a preprocess function for the HTML output.

Supposing that *mytheme* is the machine name of the theme, and I want to add a `<link>` tag for Google's Font API inclusion, this the code I would use.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['language']->language == 'en') {
    // The page is using English.
    $element = array(
      '#tag' => 'link', 
      '#attributes' => array(
        'href' => 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo&subset=latin', 
        'rel' => 'stylesheet',
        'type' => 'text/css',
      ),
    );
    drupal_add_html_head($element, 'google_font_cardo');
  }
}
```

This would add `<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo&amp;subset=latin" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` inside the `<head>` tag when the language used for the page is English.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways you can do this, but I would look into creating a custom block. Your logic that acts on the language would be in the block's output code, and you'd simply use the Block Manager to put it in the correct place in the header. This is a blog I've used before which should be useful (I'm not the author)

http://redcrackle.com/blog/how-create-block-drupal-7

In the tutorial where you see this line:

```
$block['content'] = t('Hello World!');
```

You'd instead call a function that returns the content as applicable based on the language.

Comment: If he wants to add a tag in the `head`, OP will need `template_preprocess_html`, not a block

Comment: He said "header", which is a region of the template, not "head".

Comment: Yes, the OP wrongly spoke of _header_, but the purpose of `add_action('wp_head', 'add_customcode_header')` is adding tags to  `<head>`.